# C++ Access Violation - Possibly due to a table?

Tags: c++

**Within the main function I have the following.**

```
int numRows = rowSequence.length() + 1;
int numCols = columnSequence.length() + 1;

int** twoDimTable = new int* [numRows];
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++) 
{
    twoDimTable[rowIndex] = new int [numCols];
}

//updating table
for (int i = 0; i <= numRows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= numCols; j++)
    {
        if (i == 0 || j == 0)
            twoDimTable[i][j] = 0; 

// when I start running my code I receive an unhandled exception right at the 'if' 
// statement: Access violation writing location. I looked at other similar 
// situations, but cannot seem to understand  the specific issue

        else if (rowSequence[i - 1] == columnSequence[j - 1])
            twoDimTable[i][j] = twoDimTable[i - 1][j - 1] + 1;

        else
            twoDimTable[i][j] = max(twoDimTable[i - 1][j], twoDimTable[i][j - 1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make this mistake often enough and you'll learn that <= in a for-loop is a code smell.

Comment: Using `new` is a code smell too

Comment: @HansPassant why, I would really like to know?

Comment: @Xenikh Indexed containers in C++ (including C-style arrays) generally index from 0, which means the SIZE-th element is out of range

Comment: `int numCols = columnSequence.length() + 1`;`int numRows = rowSequence.length() + 1;` -- This now begs the question -- what is `rowSequence` or `colSequence`?  They have a `length()` member function.  If they are `std::vector`'s, then what is the reason to be using `new[]` in your program?  Why not use `std::vector` instead of `new[]`?

Answer (score 2):

One problem is that your for loops are wrong; `numRows` and `numCols` are not valid indices, so they should not be included in your iterations.

That is, instead of this:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= numRows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j <= numCols; j++)
    { 
        [...]
    }
}
```

... you should have this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < numCols; j++)
    { 
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: @StackDanny the original code did protect against that (although you may have missed it due to question being poorly formatted)

Comment: yes, right.
you should rollback @JeremyFriesner